# How to store Brain Tree Transaction Details Into Database in Rails 4

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, braintree, braintree-rails

In my rails 4 application I am using Braintree sandbox testing transaction gateway. I am able to perform transactions and the transaction details are visible in my sandbox account.But my question is how to store the Transaction details into a table in my database ?

For example : The transaction ID, amount, Customer details etc. ?

My Code is given bellow :

```
def payment_process  
    @paymentamnt=@@deviceprice.to_i
    @result = Braintree::Transaction.sale(
              amount: @paymentamnt,
              payment_method_nonce: params[:payment_method_nonce])
    if @result.success?
      redirect_to payments_customers_path
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Something went wrong while processing your transaction. Please try again!"
      gon.client_token = generate_client_token
      render :new
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values you are looking for are stored in the `transaction` object of `@result`.

So you can access them like this:

```
puts @result.transaction.amount
puts @result.transaction.order_id
```

etc.

Comment: For a more comprehensive list of available attributes on `@result.transaction` you can check out the [Braintree reference docs](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/transaction/ruby). I recommend storing at least the transaction id so you can make future API calls with it.

Comment: @RyanO'Donnell : Thanks for the reply, I need one more help from you if possible, I need to get the status of all the payments done from braintree sandbox account in my website. How can I implement it ?

Comment: @PraveenGeorge In order to implement this, you would have to [find](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/find/ruby) each transaction via the transaction `id`. Then you can access the [Braintree::Transaction#status](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/transaction/ruby#status). You can also perform a [search](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/searching/search-fields/ruby) to find transactions.

Comment: @RyanO'Donnell : Thanks a lot for your help.